# Heroku Release Phase - PG Backup Before Migrations

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-migration, database-backups

With the [Heroku Release Phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) is it possible to run `pg:backups:capture`? Or is there another method to go about for creating a database backup before trying to run migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is possible, but must have heroku cli installed on your dyno and you need to authenticate it somehow. So one solution is to find or write buildpack that will install cli tool and add config variable with authentication credentials.

Another approach is to use a library such as `https://github.com/kjohnston/pgbackups-archive`. There is a problem though, it is using old heroku api, which will be disabled in April 2017. I don't know if there is any similar library that uses new api.

If you just want to backup your data and not necessarily use `pg:backups:capture`, you can just use write simple script that runs `pg_dump DATABASE_URL` with some additional options and uploads dump file to S3 or any other location. I think this is the easiest solution. Then just add this script as `release` command to Procfile.